# react component is not re-rendering after state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
export default function RenderPages({storage, setStorage, state, setState}){
  const [pageNum, setPageNum]= useState(0)

  const currentFileId=state.currentFileId
  const currentFolderId= state.currentFolderId

  return (
    <div className="writing">
      {storage[currentFolderId][currentFileId].content.map((page, index)=>
      <div className='textarea'>
        <textarea placeholder='write here' defaultValue={page} id={index} onChange={(e)=>onChange(e, index)} rows={rows} cols={cols}></textarea>
      </div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I expected that jsx would return renewal result after the state is changed, but it didn't. I checked that currentFileId and currentFolderId value were changed. why this happen?

Comment: Nothing in the code shown ever calls `setPageNum`, which is the only state setter shown.  And nothing uses or in any way observes the value `pageNum`.  Where do you think you're changing state?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are not just mutating the `state` prop.

A new reference should be created for react to know the `state` prop changed, if you just mutate `state` it is still the same reference despite some of its properties changed.

As an alternative, you could pass the values you are changing instead of the whole object:

```
export default function RenderPages({storage, setStorage, currentFileId, currentFolderId}){
  const [pageNum, setPageNum]= useState(0)

  return (
    <div className="writing">
      {storage[currentFolderId][currentFileId].content.map((page, index)=>
      <div className='textarea'>
        <textarea placeholder='write here' defaultValue={page} id={index} onChange={(e)=>onChange(e, index)} rows={rows} cols={cols}></textarea>
      </div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I defined "storage" and "state" by "useState" and they are changed at other component by "setStorage" and "setState". Is there any other way that I receive parameters as state, setState, storage, setStorage?